# Get error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 when start my node.js app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When I start my node.js app I get this error:

```
SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

What I was doing:

```
 - create a user:
CREATE USER 'main'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPass';

 - give this user all privileges
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'main'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I then try to connect through my code on production and it gives me an error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306.

But in my localhost environment it connects well. And when I try to connect to DB using command line on VPS it works too:
`mysql -umain -p`

I can't connect with code. But on my localhost it connects. Double checked my loggin and pass for DB user in .env.

Comment: Could you show us the code that connects. And also, how do you start your app.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a problem!
In my mysql config file (etc/my.cnf) was `bind-address = my VPS ip`
So, when I remove this line it starts to listen al ips.

Thanks every one!

Comment: This worked for me. I had to restart both mysql and nginx and then try to start the server again.

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting the MySQL service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding "socketPath" to my sequelize deceleration like this:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('db-name', 'user', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectOptions: {
    socketPath: 'your socket path',
    supportBigNumbers: true,
    bigNumberStrings: true
  },
});
```

find your socket path by entering /etc/mysql/mysqld.cnf:
then you have their your socket path:

```
user        = mysql
# pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# socket    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# port      = 3306
# datadir   = /var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you fall into my category, I simply forgot to put on my local server (XAMMP). You might want to check if your MySQL server is active.